# angular repeat filter on request id

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a path like `mysite.com/api/getlist/id=10`

I have a `ng-repeat` in which I would like to remove from list the value of id value request in my path.

I try with

```
ng-repeat="player in type2.players  | filter:{ player.id: '!' + $location.search().id }"
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$location` is not in a scope. But you shouldn't add it to the scope, it's a bad practice. Much better solution is to remember search `id` or filter array in controller:

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.searchId = $location.search().id;
}]);
```

View:

```
ng-repeat="player in type2.players | filter:{ player.id: !searchId }"
```

**Or:**

Filter array in controller, and use filtered array in a view:

Controller:

```
$scope.filteredPlayers = type2.players.filter(player => player.id !== searchId);
```

View:

```
ng-repeat="player in type2.filteredPlayers"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you can define custom filter expression  at controller and pass it to `filter` at template.

Controller:

```
$scope.filterCondition = function(item) {
  return item.name !== $location.search().id;    // custom filter condition
}
```

Template:

```
ng-repeat="player in type2.players | filter: filterCOndition"
```

refer below example:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {
        name: 'test1'
      },{
        name: 'test2'
      },{
        name: 'test3'
      },{
        name: 'test4'
      },{
        name: 'test5'
      }
    ];
    
    $scope.filterCOndition = function(item) {
      return item.name !== 'test1';
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: filterCOndition">
    {{item.name}}
  <div>
</div>
```